# Не работают некоторые значки Font Awesome

Tags: css3, шрифты, fontawesome

я использую Font Awesome Free 5.12.0, но в ней не отображаются некоторые значки, например вк, инстаграмма, ютуб[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы вставляете иконку? Я не вижу нужных классов Font Awesome в вашем коде.

Comment: @Neolot  через CSS #quick-contact li.quick-vk:before {
 content: "\f189";
}

Comment: Это не правильно. Читайте документацию на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно используете Font Awesome.

Вы должны вставлять иконку в том виде в котором ее дают на официальном сайте, то-есть:

`<i class="fab fa-vk"></i>`

`<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>`

`<i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>`

Вставьте эти строки во внутрь `<li>` и тогда заработает у Вас.

И на будущее, ищите нужную иконку [тут](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=vk&m=free), переходите на ее страницу и берете предоставленый `<i>` код для нее.

Comment: @ioshuk  Font Awesome можно использовать и из CSS, иначе как вы объясните что другие иконки отображаются

Comment: окей, а откуда Вы взяли тогда код для vk? - я имею ввиду класс "quick-vk"? Сами создали его или взяли из какого-то набора?

Comment: @ioshuk сам добавил

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что иконка vk относится к отдельному шрифту и к ней нужно применять `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";`

Comment: @НиколайПарахневич, как раз таки является.